# Docker Windows Host Linux Container

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

How does it work that I can have a Windows Host system and still running Linux containers? Docker doesn't have any Hypervisor it manages resources with the kernel of the Host system. Does that mean my Windows Kernel manages the resources for my Linux Containers? How can my Linux Container even run doesn't they need a Linux Kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation Docker Desktop for Windows uses the Hyper-V hypervisor.

> Docker Desktop for Windows requires Microsoft Hyper-V to run. The Docker Desktop for Windows installer enables Hyper-V for you, if needed, and restarts your machine.

If your machine doesn't support Hyper-V then VirtualBox will be used.

> Note: If your system does not meet the requirements to run Docker Desktop for Windows, you can install Docker Toolbox, which uses Oracle Virtual Box instead of Hyper-V.

In either case a hypervisor *is* used.

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/